# Slack conversation.list api is not listing private channels as well as direct messages where the bot is part of

Tags: node.js, axios, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Im using the bot token to get the channel list, but im only getting the public channels not private channels and DMs where the bot has been added to

Here is the permission i have

[`channels:read`](https://api.slack.com/scopes/channels:read)[`groups:read`](https://api.slack.com/scopes/groups:read)[`im:read`](https://api.slack.com/scopes/im:read)[`mpim:read`](https://api.slack.com/scopes/mpim:read)

```
const response = await axios.post('https://slack.com/api/conversations.list', {
        exclude_archived: true,
        types:
          "public_channel,private_channel,mpim,im"
      } ,{
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
      });
      const channels = response.data.channels;
    
      const channelList = channels.map((channel) => {
        if(!channel.is_archived){
          return{
            channel_name: channel.name_normalized,
            channel_id: channel.id
          }
          
        return undefined;   
      })
      .filter((channel) => channel !== undefined)
```

The bot token will be something like this xoxe.xoxb-1-MS0yLTUyNjI5ODk.......

Why i cant get the private channels ? the bot has been authorized in the workspace.

Comment: Figured it out, it seems the http request will not give the list of private channels , so switched to slack node sdk and its works fine 

`const response = await client.conversations.list({
        exclude_archived: true,
        types:
          "public_channel,private_channel,mpim",
        limit: 1000
      })`

Comment: With the original code above, you're not taking into account pagination. Even when asking for a page of 100 results, you can get fewer and the conversations you're looking for could be on another virtual page of results. When using the Slack Node SDK pagination is handled for you.